# Manipulate datagridview column in 3 tier architecture

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, 3-tier

I am currently on a project that does management of interns. Every intern has projects. Also every project has steps/points. If intern completes an step, project increases its progress. So basically, every project has a progress.

I'm using an custom DataGridViewProgressColumn. After adding this column to my datagridview, I can change it's value with just setting its value to something.

```
//Last index of datagridview is progresscolumn.
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1].Value = value;
```

This value is coming from database, as far as I know, I shouldn't access to database from UI layer. But datagridview is at UI layer.

I have 2 solutions in my mind:

1. Set every value of progresscolumn at data access layer: I dont think this is possible although I think this is best solution: I just cant change the value of -not placed- progressColumn.
2. Set every value of progresscolumn at UI layer, probably "working but against of architecture" solution.

How can i solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: My database is ms-sql, if it is important.

Comment: The progress value should be a property of your model and you should bind `DataGridView` to a list of `Model`. Your methods in Service Layer should return list of `Model`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, I just used a DAL function that returns an int value. That function calculates the value and returns it.

```
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1].Value = DAL.getValue(rowID);
```